# font change for Tamil and English using PHP accept multiple language

Tags: php, jquery

```js
    $('input[type=radio][name=language]').change(function() {
        if (this.value == 'tamil') {
            //$('#question').val('');
             
            $('#question').attr('placeholder', 'Nfs;tpia cs;splTk;');
            $('#question').css('font-family', "Geethapria");
        }
        else if (this.value == 'english') {
            //$('#question').val('');
            $('#question').attr('placeholder', 'Enter Question');
            $('#question').css('font-family', "inherit");
         }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group form-show-validation row">
        <label for="name" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 mt-sm-2 text-right">Language <span class="required-label">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-9 col-sm-8">
                <label class="co-t">
                    <input type="radio" name="language" value="english" checked> English<br> 
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4">
                <label class="co-t">
                    <input type="radio" name="language" value="tamil"> Tamil<br>
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4">
                <label class="co-t">
                    <input type="text" name="language_text" id="question" placeholder=""> 
                </label>
            </div>
     </div>
```

here,
singe input field should accept multiple language. While i change it to English, previously entered other language should not changed to English.

We used two languages Akshar and Geethapriya. Please suggest me to get the output.